# Le sens de l'ancien mot « porpos »

Tags: anglais, sens, étymologie, histoire, ancien-français

En anglais, il y a le mot « *purpose* » que l'on peut traduire par :

- raison
- objet
- but
- objectif

« *Purpose* » vient de l'ancien mot français « porpos ».  La forme verbale est « porposer ».  [On peut voir l'étymologie ici.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=purpose&allowed_in_frame=0) Le site-web traduit ce mot par « *intention* » en anglais (« l'intention » ou « le but », en français).

Je voudrais vérifier le sens de cet ancien mot « porpos », savoir s'il correspond vraiment aux mots « intention » et « but ».

Answer (score 5, accepted):

« Porposer » est tout simplement une variante en ancien français de « proposer ».
En ancien français l'orthographe est approximative et par ailleurs ce qui est passé en anglais s'est fait sur la base de l'oral.
La seule variante du mot qui soit arrivée jusqu'à nous est « proposer » qui veut dire *propose/suggest*.
On retrouve tout de même dans « proposer » la notion d'intention qu'il y a en anglais dans *purpose* dans l'expression « Mon propos est de... » (*I entend to tell you*... *My purpose is to tell you*..)

Comment: Oui, c'est juste. A rapprocher du sens de *proposer* dans l'expression *se proposer de [faire quelque chose]*

Comment: Le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/proposer) cite « se purposer de » (étym. 2.b). Le [Dictionnaire du moyen français](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/proposer?idf=dmfXdXpcYpcj;str=0) cite plusieurs exemples avec la racine *pourpos*. Je pense qu'il s'agit d'une évolution semblable à *pro* → *pour*, qui n'a pas pris.